# Adding elements to a container in reverse order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm adding an element to a `ul` container when checked true of another list of checkboxes. It is done as follows.

```
const addedList = document.getElementById("columns");

if($(this).is(":checked")){
            
            addedList.innerHTML += `<div>Test div number{num}</div>`

}
```

My issue is when done like this the first element added is at the top of the container and the last element added is at the last.

But i want to show the last element added at the top.

I have done a css only solution like this

```
 #columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```

It works fine but as my added divs have the drag and drop capability, the added css messes up with that capability. So i'm trying to implement a solution using javascript. How can i reverse the order of the elements inside my `addedList`

Comment: `$(this).is` is jQuery. Why not 1. tag jQuery, 2. use jQuery or 3, Not use jQuery at all?

Comment: Or at least proper DOM methods like `.append()` or `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

Comment: Or jQuery `.before()`

Comment: i used insertAdjacentHTML but still it appends in the same direction as before